# Can iOS BLE selectively connect to a given peripheral in the presence of others of same type

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm starting to doubt whether this is even possible. I'd be grateful if someone could tell me if I'm wasting my time:

I have created a custom PCB using a PSoC4 BLE module.  I plan to have some number of these same units within the BLE operating distance of a similar number of iPads.  I want to be able to pair/bond/connect a given iPad to one and only one of these peripheral units and each unit be able to connect to only the one iPad.

The ipad will be running an app specifically designed for this and will include a provision to specify which peripheral unit to connect to.

I've tried using different local names in each peripheral which works fine when only one peripheral is advertising but when two or more are advertising the iPad seems to not care what the local names are and will sometimes connect to the one with a different local name.

Is this a place to be using PSoC's public address or what should I do (if it really is possible to do this)?

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: Your iOS app needs to scan for the peripherals and decide which one it wants to connect to (often you show a list to the user and get them to decide). You then store the `CBPeripheral` `identifier` value so that you can identify this peripheral in the future and connect to it. Can you show some code from your iOS app that shows how you are currently identifying the peripheral you want to connect to?